# How to define integer variables for a generic class in java?

Tags: java

I have a short class:

```
public class Stack {

private int[] data;
private int Top;

Public Stack(int size) {

   data = new int[size];
   top = -1;

}

public void Push (int value) {

   top++;
   data[top] = value;

}

public int pop() {

   return data[top--];

}

public int top() {

   return data[top];

}
```

And i'm getting bunch of errors "cannot convert from int to T"...
And also getting an error in the array definition of the constructor...

This is my code, i'm a beginner please help me to understand this:

```
public class Stack <T> {


    private T[] data;
    private T top;

    Public Stack(T size) {

    data = new T[size];// im getting error here "cannot create a generic array of T...
    top = -1; // what should I do with this?

    }

    public void Push (T value) {

    top++; //cannot convert from int to T
    data[top] = value; //cannot convert from int to T

    }

    public T pop() {

    return data[top--]; //cannot convert from int to T

    }

    public T top() {

    return data[top]; //cannot convert from int to T

   }
```

Comment: MAn,your code is incomplete as you haven't shown the main() method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say why you tried to convert all the "int"s to "T"s, but I can already say:

- "public" (visibility of the constructor) should be without the capital.
- Your variable "top" must be an int : whatever the type T, the variable top is an index.
- You can not create a generic array. Instead of giving a size to the constructor, you should write the constructor to take an array of T.

  ```
  public class Stack<T> {

      private final T[] data;
      private int top;

      public Stack(final T[] data) {
          this.data = data;
          top = -1;
      }

      public void Push(final T value) {
          top++;
          data[top] = value;
      }

      public T pop() {
          return data[top--];
      }

      public T top() {
          return data[top];
      }
  }
  ```

edit: I also added "final" to the field "data" because I always declare "final" everything I can.

Comment: thanks man. this works. but is there a way I can keep the constructor as it is and still get it to be generic..? maybe with a wrapper class? because i'm sure I should change it's parameters..@syme

Comment: I do not understand your new question because it is generic, and you can not create a generic array.

Comment: public class Stack<E extends Integer> { 

    private Integer[] data; 

    public Stack(int size) {
        data = new Integer[size];
    }

    ...
}

Comment: something like this..@syme

Comment: Oh yes ! Sorry I did not thought you wanted to specify your class Stack for Integers only.

Answer (score 1):

Your `top` variable is meant to store an index into your array representing the top of the stack.  It's not meant to store any actual data; it's just an index.  Therefore, when making your `Stack` class generic, it should not be converted to type `T`.  It should remain an `int`.

The parameter to your constructor, `size`, must be of type `int` also.  As for creating generic arrays, please refer to [How to: generic array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation).

Comment: oh, got you. thanks. and about the rest? i mean, now i still have the prob with the array @rgettman